# Save to txt (java)

Tags: java

How can I make the below code, save the webpage it self to txt file, I don't need the code of the webpage I need the webpage itself to be saved as text, like when we press CTRL + S and choose save as txt.
As well, how to make the browse hidden.
Thank you in advance :)

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
    String url = "http://w3-01.ibm.com/pc/entitle/pg2/Service.wss/mts/Lookup?type=8205&serial=06202ET";
    d.browse(new URI(url));
}
}
```

Comment: " I don't need the code of the webpage I need the webpage itself" - a web page is a bunch of HTML, with possibly some JavaScript or other content. It's "code". If you want to extract some data from it, you'll need to parse it. Search for that, it's a frequent question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working example in Java 8:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
        String file = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "google.txt";
        System.out.println("Saving file to " + file);
        try (InputStream in = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                os.write(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This always gives me this error
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \tmp\google.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
 at Main1.main(Main1.java:12)

Comment: Change `String file = "/tmp/google.txt";` to a path that is writeable on your system.

Comment: If you're using windows `/tmp/google.txt` won't work. Change it to a valid windows-compatible path.

Comment: NoW IT SAYS
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \temp (Access is denied)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
 at Main1.main(Main1.java:12)

Comment: Looks like your user does not have access to write to `\temp`? Should it be instead `C:\temp`? Try a path you know your user can write to, such as your desktop.

Comment: Also, don't forget to include the filename (`google.txt` in my example code) in the path too.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: You can also try `String file = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "google.txt";` which should always succeed (unless your disk is full).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, but it is not what I want, I don't want the code of the page to be saved as text, I want to save the page itself as text, like when you do CTRL + S and choose save as txt.
Can this be done please?

Comment: So you want the javascript run which might impact the DOM? For that you will need to use something like HTMLUnit or a headless Chrome browser.

Comment: Hello

I have created a small program that can scan txt files.

I want to know how to make the below if statment, print the next line if the word Small was find in the line.

int lineNumber = 1;
        while(scnr.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scnr.nextLine();
            if (line.contains("small")) {
             System.out.println(line);
            }